# InfoPath form closes and redirects to deleted SharePoint library?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, document-library, infopath

When a user clicks submit for the first time, the form closes and they are redirected to an old library that I deleted. But if they were to go back and edit their form then submit again, it will redirect to the correct library. Why does it redirect to the old library, and is there a way to fix this?

Using InfoPath and SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the link they are using to initially create the form? Is it embedded in navigation or in a content page? If so, look at the url query string, and make sure the SaveLocation query string argument points to the right place.